# Getting TMS tiles without clamping to Byte range

Tags: tiles, tile-map-service

How I can get TMS tiles (Z/X/Y.png) without getting them clamped in data range (e.g. GeoTIFF UInt16 -> Gdal2Tiles -> TMS UInt16 instead of GeoTIFF UInt16 -> Gdal2Tiles -> TMS Byte)?

Comment: By editing the source code of gdal2tiles or by cutting the tiles with some other tool, like gdal_translate tile by tile with the -spat option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is [rasterio](https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio) extension named [rio-tiler](https://github.com/cogeotiff/rio-tiler) that can cut your georaster in TMS tiles. It has far more possibilities than gdal2tiles (I really tried to change gdal2tiles code, but I found it very hard to understand it), and it does not require you to convert georaster to uint8 before tiling your TIFF.

The usage example of it is quite simple:

```
from rio_tiler.io import COGReader

with COGReader("my.tif") as image:
    img = image.tile(x, y, z) # read mercator tile z-x-y
```